# Convert String to arrayList in groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a string like: `String str = "[aa,bb,cc,dd]"`. I want to convert this to a list in groovy like `[aa, bb, cc, dd]`. Any groovy method available for this type conversion?

Comment: In case you got this string because you do an (accidental) `toString` on a "real" list, you are better off preventing that. This is an accident to happen otherwise: `["1,2"].toString() => [1,2]`

Comment: I need to store a list in database also return that as list ,can you give me better solution.

Comment: Use a format, that is made to (de)serialize data and pick one, that is able to hold the data type you want.  E.g. for a List<String> you can use JSON.  Or since you are on Grails already, why not make it a List<String> on a GORM class and just store it as what it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try as below :-

```
String str = "[aa,bb,cc,dd]"
assert str[1..str.length()-2].tokenize(',') == ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Perhaps simplify a bit:   tokenize('[,]')

Comment: `str[1..str.lenght()-2]` can be simplified to `str[1..-2]`

Answer (score 9):

Using regexp replaceAll

```
String str = "[aa,bb,cc,dd]"
def a = str.replaceAll(~/^\[|\]$/, '').split(',')
assert a == ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
```

EDIT:

The following version is a bit more verbose but handles extra white spaces

```
String str = " [ aa , bb , cc , dd ] "
def a = str.trim().replaceAll(~/^\[|\]$/, '').split(',').collect{ it.trim()}
assert a == ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
String str= "['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']"
assert Eval.me(str) == ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']
```

`Eval` is what you need.

Comment: If this string come from an external system, or a user, it's not really secure to use Eval for this. I prefer to use a real parser/regex for this than eval

Comment: @JérémieB, yes you're right, in such scenario it's much better to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

another way w/o replaceAll & tokenize:

```
def s = '[aa,bb,cc,dd]'
def a = []
s.eachMatch( /[\[]?([^\[\],]+)[,\]]?/ ){ a << it[ 1 ] }
assert '[aa, bb, cc, dd]' == a.toString()
```